Is "Category 6A Ethernet Cable" the suitable usage in English?
I am looking for the suitable translation for the Chinese phrase "超六类网线".

"Category" is often abbreviated. "cat 6A" may placed after or before "Ethernet cable".

Or just "Cat6A cable".

Have you tried a Google search? I was surprised that 'Cat'/'CAT' persists in English, but it does. 'USB 3.0', 'USB C', 'RJ11' etc see no need to spell out that these are categories or types.

You need the "Cat" in "Cat 5", "Cat 6E", etc because just calling it "5" and "6" doesn't indicate what the number refers to and there isn't another commonly-known identifier. Compare "4G", "5G", where the G refers to "generation". It's become conventional. And note it's common to refer to "USB type C" as well as "USB C", there are products known as "release 2" or "version 2" not just "2", etc.

Yes, Category 6A Ethernet Cable is the most accurate translation for the Chinese phrase "超六类网线". As the commenters noted, this is commonly abbreviated to Cat 6a, as seen in the "Cable Category" filter of a search for Ethernet Cables on Amazon.com.

However, be careful because this is not a perfect translation. Cat 6a is an international standard, whereas "超六类" is not. Instead, it translates to "Super Category 6", so we're simply assuming that "Super" refers to the higher quality Cat 6a cable versus a regular Cat 6 or purpose-specific Cat 8.

Just be a little careful that cat6A isn't interpreted as regular cat6 with T568A connectors, as opposed to T568B connectors.
